# How do run commands in background one by one?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, nohup

```
nohup php /home/www/api/24 > 24.out 2> 24.err < /dev/null
nohup php /home/www/api/27 > 27.out 2> 27.err < /dev/null
nohup php /home/www/api/19 > 27.out 2> 16.err < /dev/null
```

I have a few thousand api calls I need to make and need to be done one by one so I don't flood the other server with web calls. After I run the sh file, how can I close the terminal without interrupting the process, CTRL+Z ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You type...

```
$ screen
```

...and hit enter.

Run the command or script.

Press control-a, then d

Then you can disconnect, log out, do whatever... come back later and check on the script:

```
$ screen -r
```

Then you wonder how you ever got along without it.

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

Comment: Yep, screen is extremely neat. I've been using it for decades.

Comment: "Then you wonder how you ever got along without it." Amen brother.

Answer (score 2):

Put everything in a script, and then run that script with `nohup`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 24 27 19 ...
do
    php /home/www/api/$i > $i.out 2> $i.err
done
```

Then do:

```
nohup /path/to/script </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: @user962449, you may be thinking of `&&` which executes the right hand side if the left hand side exited successfully `[[ a == a ]] && echo yes`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [batch(1)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/batch.htm) command with a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), e.g:

```
 batch << EOJ
   php /home/www/api/24 > 24.out 2> 24.err < /dev/null
   php /home/www/api/17 > 17.out 2> 17.err < /dev/null
   php /home/www/api/19 > 19.out 2> 19.err < /dev/null
 EOJ
```